# iOS - Having multiple Table View Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I'm having a bit of trouble with my xcode project.  Basically, I'm trying to use two View Controllers, each one having it's own Table View.  Let's say the first one would have a list of articles and the second would have a list of videos.

In my ViewController.m file I have:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _articles = @[
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"swaag"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"164"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"124"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"185"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"123"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"194"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"249"},
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeff", @"subHeadline": @"784"},
            ];

    _videos = @[
            @{@"Headline": @"Jeffers", @"subHeadline": @"swag"}
            ];


UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
[tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UITableView *tableView2 = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
[tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.articles count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView2:(UITableView *)tableView2 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.videos count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *rowData = self.articles[indexPath.row];
    cell.headline = rowData[@"Headline"];
    cell.subHeadline = rowData[@"subHeadline"];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView2:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary *rowData = self.videos[indexPath.row];
    cell.headline = rowData[@"Headline" ];
    cell.subHeadline = rowData[@"subHeadline"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

And I have tableview2 because I'm trying to use videos for ONLY my second ViewController.  Even when I change tags, I get a Thread 1: Signal SIGABART error.

Help? Sorry if I didn't give enough info to give proper advice.  This is my first time asking a question on this.

Comment: In what line does the error occur? what does the stack trace show?

Comment: You have everything set up very wrong and there's too much to give you a single easy answer. No offense, but you would be much better starting with a tutorial and THOROUGHLY read Apple's documentation on Delegates and MVC design

Comment: Actually I realized that my tags on my storyboard were off.  So now I have that the one that needs to display articles has a tag of 1, and the one that needs to display videos has a tag of 2.  But for some reason when the videos table displays, it just takes the same data as articles and displays _articles data, even though I want it to take data from _videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate method is called tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: The method tableView2: cellForRowAtIndexPath: is not a delegate method. It will never, ever get called.

What you need to do in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: and tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: is to look at the tableView parameter and see which of your two tableViews it is. I would probably have two properties, one for tableView1 and tableView2 (calling the first one tableView1 and not tableView2 will avoid some confusion), and check like

```
if (tableView == self.tableView1)
{
    ...
}
else if (tableView == self.tableView2)
{
    ....
}
```

Also have a look at your user interface and see if you can't use one table view with two sections.

Comment: Thanks! this worked for me.  I know my code is a bit amateurish, this is my first time using XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that you have a separate UIViewController for each tableView. Often, the viewController, delegate (and also the datasource) are in the same class. It can be a lot of code for one table in once class already. Therefore, you should split it up. If you do so and you are using storyboard with UIViewControllers, your whole screen would need a UIViewController by itself. There exists something like a "Container" you can choose in the storyboard for the sub-viewController.

Furthermore, your comment about the tags: Do not use them to find your views again (unless you are in some kind of "generic magic" code which might need refactoring). You should use IBOutlet for that.